# Intellij + Gradle: Import classes automatically

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle, ide, gradlew

I am writing a gradle build file. I want to use the dependency [`Apache Commons Net v3.3`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net/3.3).

Now, whenever I type a statement that uses a class from this dependency, IntelliJ does not recognize that I am missing a import. I was aldo not offered any classes from the previously added dependency. I did indeed click the refresh button on the gradle tab in IntelliJ IDEA, before I added any dangling content to my buildscript.

When I run `gradlew` now (and it compiles the buildscript), I get a error about a unrecognized Symbol.

Can I do something to make IntelliJ report missing imports to me?

I can add the import by looking up the javadoc online any manually copy-pasting the class name into my buildscript, but I find that rather annoying and I think that such primitive tasks should be done by a IDE.

This is pretty much the exact example:

```
apply plugin: 'java'


buildscript {
    repositories {
         jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    }
}

task example << {
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient() //IntelliJ does not complain about missing imports, neither did it have the correct class available in auto-completion
}
```

Comment: It is done by the ide. How have you imported your gradle build file into intellij? Dies the library show in the project dependencies in the navigator pane?

Comment: @tim_yates yes, it does show up properly and it also does the auto-refreshes once I have stopped typing for a while.

Comment: How have you added this dependency? Are you sure you added it to the appropriate configuration (i.e. compile, and not runtime, for example). Does IntelliJ list this library under the Compile scope?

Comment: also be sure to not add it to the buildscript part.  it would really help, if you could provide a (minimal) failing version of your build.gradle file. also be sure to have intellij configured to use the custom wrapper and make sure the settings are in sync.

Comment: @cfrick added a snippet that i typed onmy mobile, forgive the occasional possible typo.

Comment: oh you mean _in_ the gradle file.  to my knowledge intellij has close no clue, whats going on in a gradle file.  it just utilizes the tooling api from it to get tasks and make them run.

Comment: @cfrick After a while it does know about them and inserts fully qualified names on return-press. It also offers the packages on import statements (when typing them manually) but it's not reliable about when it starts working and about the fact that it does not report missing imports.

Answer (score 0):

Install the gradle plugin (which it seems like you already have).

Go to the gradle tab on the right side of the IDE and click the wrench icon to get to gradle settings.

Check the box that says "Use auto-import"